# I'm getting this and I've tried using boot repair minimal bash-like line editing is supported

Tags: boot-repair

Below is my pastebin. Please I need help

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Y56W6kq5jx/

Comment: Only current versions are supported here. Ubuntu 23.04 ‘Lunar Lobster’ ends in January of 2024
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/lunar-lobster-release-notes/31910 Please install current 22.04.3 or 23.10.

Comment: I used the live usb to get the pastebin but on my external drive, Ubuntu 22.04 is installed but I am getting minimal bash-like line editing is supported whenever I boot from the drive

Comment: It looks like your install is correct. The GUID/partUUID in ESP is using the correct ESP on sdc and the 3 line grub in ESP refers to the install in sdc.  What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: Dell latitude e3410

Comment: Dell typically works well. Is sdc an external drive? If so you may have to directly boot it from UEFI menu using devicelike you do for that live installer, not "ubuntu".

Comment: So what happens on a fresh boot? Where do you end up?